# java keyPressed event

Tags: java, swing

I have read many answer from stack overflow but can't solve my problem so i am posting question

i have written code for Key Press Action in java swing but nothing is happening when  ever i am pressing key so please advice where i have written wrong codes my codes are as under

```
textField_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_TAB){    try{
                String query="select * from checklist where sbno='"+sb+"'";
                PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()){
                    Shipping_Marks.setText(rs.getString("smarks"));
                    Shippername.setText(rs.getString("shipper"));

                }           
                rs.close();
            }catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
```

Comment: add only `System.out.print("pressed");` and test again

Comment: its also not working

Comment: yes so when you post a question post only relavant minimum code.the database part doesn't requred here

Comment: *"I have read many answer from stack overflow .."* Link the top 3, and explain why they did not work for you. Note that if you saw 'many answers' it is likely that some of them mentioned component focus, as well as components consuming the event. OTOH there is nothing in that uncompilable code snippet which might tell us if either of those things is happening. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  It is also common for answers related to Swing and `KeyListener` to mention key bindings. Have you tried them?

Comment: @AndrewThompson feel free to join us in [campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) for java closing anytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab is intercepted before it goes to the field. If you want to intercept Tab you have to use work around or, better, don't use Tab as the Key to intercept.

[No Tab key-pressed or key-released events are received by the key
 event listener. This is because the focus subsystem consumes focus
 traversal keys, such as Tab and Shift Tab.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

General idea is that Tab is used to switch between components. That's the main function of it.

Another approach (for you) could be to exclude this field from traveling by Tab like this:

```
text_Field1.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
```

or you can use the fact that this field loses focus and use methods which catch this event.
Here is some [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) to do so.

Comment: how to use container

Comment: i m new pls saw some example

Comment: sir i have tried action event performed for this and it is working with enter key but i want set this to tab key

Comment: Tab is used to move between fields. Field itself doesn't see it.

Comment: thank you sir text_Field1.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); worked perfectly for my app thank you very much